# Add tag to list on enter, but don't submit form when in tag_entry

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using a QLineEdit to enter items into a QListWidget.  Users can enter 0-many tags, hitting enter each time to add the tag to the list.  How can I get it to stop trying to submit the form each time enter is pressed while in the tag_entry QLineEdit?

```
    def create_widgets(self):
        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        tags_label = QLabel("Tags:")
        self.tags_list_widget = QListWidget()
        self.tags_list_widget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.remove_tag)  # Handle double click to remove a tag
        self.tags_entry = QLineEdit()
        self.tags_entry.setPlaceholderText("Enter a tag and press Enter")
        self.tags_entry.returnPressed.connect(self.add_tag_on_enter)  # Handle Enter key press
        save_button = QPushButton("Save")
        save_button.clicked.connect(self.save_it)
        layout.addRow(tags_label, self.tags_list_widget)
        layout.addRow(self.tags_entry)
        layout.addRow(save_button)

    def add_tag_on_enter(self):
        tag = self.tags_entry.text().strip()
        if tag:
            # Add the tag to the list widget
            item = QListWidgetItem(tag)
            self.tags_list_widget.addItem(item)
            self.tags_list.append(tag)
            self.tags_entry.clear()
        else:
            # If the tags_entry is empty, do nothing
            pass

    def remove_tag(self, item):
        tag = item.text()
        # Confirm before removing the tag
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, "Remove Tag", f"Are you sure you want to remove the tag '{tag}'?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.tags_list_widget.takeItem(self.tags_list_widget.row(item))
            self.tags_list.remove(tag)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stop trying to submit the form"?